# Excel COUNTIFS Assistance with Duplicate Values & Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, multiple-columns, countif

Struggling to figure out accurate formulas to return the results I'm looking for. I have the following data:

```
| CLIENT |SERVICE TYPE| 
|--------|------------|
|  JANE  |     A      |
|  JOHN  |     A      |
|  JOHN  |     B      |
|  BOB   |     A      |
|  BOB   |     B      |
|  BOB   |     B      |
|  JIM   |     B      |
|  JOAN  |     A      |
|  JOAN  |     B      |
|  SUE   |     A      |
|  SUE   |     B      |
|  SUE   |     B      |
```

I want this data to provide three values:

**1)** The total # of A's in column B... I'm using: `=COUNTIF(B:B,"A")`

**2)** The total # of occurrences exactly 1 Service Type A and 1 Service Type B for the same Client (summing all occurences into one cell).

**3)** The total # of occurrences exactly 1 Service Type A and 2 or more Service Type B's for the same Client (summing all occurrences into one cell).

The result should be:

**1)** 5

**2)** 2

**3)** 2

Comment: A sample data set containing the expected outcome we could work on would be great so that we could better visualize what you're trying to achieve. Likewise, providing the formulas you've tried so far for nos. 2 and 3 may help us in understand the exact requirement.

Comment: I've included a sample "DATA SET"  with the expected outcome. The formulas for No.'s 2 & 3 have proven too complicated for me to determine thus far.

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: I attempted to clean up my data to alleviate any columns that didn't pertain to the question at hand and simplified my example. I attempted to use the Markdown Table Generator but when pasting it was jumbled and unclear, so I entered it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are better ways to do this, but the use of a helper column would help us calculate correctly. Assuming your clients and service types are in columns A and B respectively (with data starting at row 2), enter the following formula in cell C2 and drag down until your last row of data:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$C1,3,0),"")="",IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"A")=1,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"B")=1),"x",IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"A")=1,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"B")>=2),"y","")),"")
```

What this does is it puts an `x` value beside the name that meets your condition in no. 2, and `y` in no. 3. If it detects that a name has already an `x` or `y` value in the previous rows, it will skip labeling that name with `x` or `y`.

A simple `COUNTIF` would then enable us to count how many `x's` or `y's` are in column C.

`=COUNTIF(C:C,"x")` would count all no. of unique clients meeting your number 2 condition, while a `=COUNTIF(C:C,"y")` would do the same thing for number 3 condition.

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted your post but I'm less than 15 posts so it doesn't show.

Comment: @B-Millionaire, that's alright. It's the thought that counts. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//If THER NOTE = 1
=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C, "Marley,Bob", D:D,"THER NOTE") = 1,COUNTIFS(C:C, "Marley,Bob", D:D,"DA")+COUNTIFS(C:C, "Marley,Bob", D:D,"THER NOTE"),0)

//If THER NOTE = 2
=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C, "Marley,Bob", D:D,"THER NOTE") = 2,COUNTIFS(C:C, "Marley,Bob", D:D,"DA")+COUNTIFS(C:C, "Marley,Bob", D:D,"THER NOTE"),0)
```

Comment: That would only give me a total of clients named Bob Marley. I am trying to get a total count (in one cell) of how many instances the Staff member had a DA and only 1 Ther Note. I also need the same in a different cell for 1 DA and 2 or more Ther Notes.

Comment: I went ahead and changed it above, let me know if that works out for the first part.

Comment: I'm not sure you are understanding my question. The specific client doesn't matter. It is the Staff Name and the Service Type cobmination (DA & Ther Note) that matter. I don't want my formula to just count "Marley, Bob". I want to count how many times Tom Jones sees any client for exactly 1 DA and 1 Ther Note and then total those occurences in one cell.